# eslint throws error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

i am new android beginner and try to deploy firebase functions but show some error how to solve this problem plz help me.

**Firebase database structure**

**User Table**

- Users

  - user_id

    - device_token : user_device_token
    - Name : user_name

**Notification Table**

- notifications

  - to_user_id

    - notification_id

      - from : from_user_id

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx06I.png)

**Index.js**

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


/*
 * 'OnWrite' works as 'addValueEventListener' for android. It will fire the function
 * everytime there is some item added, removed or changed from the provided 'database.ref'
 * 'sendNotification' is the name of the function, which can be changed according to
 * your requirement
 */

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {


   /*
    * You can store values as variables from the 'database.ref'
    * Just like here, I've done for 'user_id' and 'notification'
    */

   const user_id = event.params.user_id;
   const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

   console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);

   /*
    * Stops proceeding to the rest of the function if the entry is deleted from database.
    * If you want to work with what should happen when an entry is deleted, you can replace the
    * line from "return console.log.... "
    */

   if(!event.data.val()){

   return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);

  }

   /*
    * 'fromUser' query retreives the ID of the user who sent the notification
    */

   const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');

   return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

   const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;

   console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);

   /*
    * The we run two queries at a time using Firebase 'Promise'.
    * One to get the name of the user who sent the notification
    * another one to get the devicetoken to the device we want to send notification to
    */

   const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${from_user_id}/Name`).once('value');
   const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

   return Promise.all([userQuery, deviceToken]).then(result => {

     const userName = result[0].val();
     const token_id = result[1].val();

     /*
      * We are creating a 'payload' to create a notification to be sent.
      */

     const payload = {
     notification: {
       title : "New Friend Request",
       body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
       icon: "default",
     
     }
    };

     /*
      * Then using admin.messaging() we are sending the payload notification to the token_id of
      * the device we retreived.
      */

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

      console.log('This was the notification Feature');

     });

   });

  });

 });
```

**cmd show error **

> C:\Users\TahirAliAwan\Desktop\Function>firebase deploy
>   === Deploying to 'videochat-96f75'...
>   i  deploying functions
>   Running command: npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint
>   functions@ lint C:\Users\TahirAliAwan\Desktop\Function\functions
>   eslint .
>   C:\Users\TahirAliAwan\Desktop\Function\functions\index.js
>     61:11  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
>     84:14  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
>     84:69  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
>   ✖ 3 problems (1 error, 2 warnings)
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" "C:\Users\TahirAliAwan\Desktop\Function\functions" "run" "lint"
>   npm ERR! node v6.11.5
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script 'eslint .'.
>   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the functions package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     eslint .
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs functions
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls functions
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\TahirAliAwan\Desktop\Function\npm-debug.log
>   Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Comment: are you retreiving the `userid` twice? Also remove the .`then` function you won't get an error

Comment: When showing errors on Stack Overflow, please copy the entire text of the error into the question instead of showing an image.  That makes it easier to read and easier to search.

Comment: Your error output shows two warnings from TSLint and one error about always returning a value from then(). Between all those messages, it's suggesting that you restructure the promises in your code.

Comment: @Tahiraliawan did you remove the `.then(response => {

      console.log('This was the notification Feature');`?

Comment: @Peter Hadded i removed this line but one error remaining.  ` 61:11  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting`

Comment: make sure you have the latest nodejs

Comment: Node v6.11.5 and Npm 3.10.10

Comment: Thank @PeterHaddad  i am using latest nodejs it's working.

Comment: Hi @Tahiraliawan, I understand your issue is now solved, is that right? Please, post the solution to your issue as an answer (and accept it) so that the community solves that this question is already solved, and future visitors can see the solution straight away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @PeterHaddad tip and my effort, I solved this problem by removing this line 
`.then(response => { console.log('This was the notification Feature');` and update nodejs.
Thanks to all.